# Combine Multiple Columns in Single field

Tags: ms-access

![WELD TRACKING DATABASE][1]

Hi Guys!

I hope you can help me with my problem.
I'm having 6 columns (Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6), each row is having a unique ID.
Now, I trying to merge/combine the 6 columns in one single field but I'm stuck with + and & operations. I want the query result to be as below.

Row1 (Col1=10 Col2=10, Col3=10, Col4=10, Col5=10, Col6=10; Query=10)
Row2 (Col1=10 Col2=10, Col3=20, Col4=20, Col5=30, Col6=30; Query=10/20/30)
Row3 (Col1=10 Col2=20, Col3=30, Col4=40, Col5=50, Col6=60; Query=10/20/30/40/50/60)

Thank you guys in advance!

Answer (score 0):

First I would like to say I think you should revisit the way you are storing your data.  Chances are it isn't setup "correctly" if you feel the need to group by columns this way.  More often than not it is an issue with the way you store data.  I could be mistaken but with the given information feels that way.

To solve your acutal problem I would use a custom function.  I can't think of a way to query and group by columns using only SQL

Throw the function in a module and call it in your query (e.g. `CombinedColumns: GroupByColumns([a],[b],[c],[d],[e],[f])`) where `a,b,c,d,e,f` are field names

```
Function GroupByColumns(ParamArray flds())
    Dim dict As Dictionary
    Dim key
    Dim i As Long

    Set dict = New Dictionary
    For i = LBound(flds) To UBound(flds)
        If dict.Exists(flds(i)) = False Then
            dict.Add flds(i), flds(i)
        End If
    Next
    For Each key In dict.Keys
        If GroupByColumns = "" Then
            GroupByColumns = key
        Else
            GroupByColumns = GroupByColumns & "/" & key
        End If
    Next
End Function
```